# Execute auto.arima two different solutions in Windows and MAC

Tags: arima, autocorrelation

I have been working on in a project for university with the following data.

[data](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz6D1fs3afrGV2hDREYtUWh2WDlqbEphdW1kajA5VHBMTnJn/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel)

I executed the `auto.arima` in *Windows* and *Mac* and I got different results. In *Mac* I got and `NaN` warning message. Any idea why this could be?

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("tseries")
install.packages("forecast")

library(ggplot2)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

library(readxl)
via_dat <- read_excel("Viajeros.xlsx")
via <- ts(via_dat[,-1], start=c(1999,1), frequency=12)
via_train <- window(via, end=c(2018,12))

fitvia <- auto.arima(log(via_train), seasonal=TRUE)
checkresiduals(fitvia)
print(fitvia)
```

**Output in *Windows***

```
Series: log(via_train) 
ARIMA(4,0,0)(1,1,1)[12] with drift 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3      ar4    sar1     sma1   drift
      0.6280  0.1756  0.0903  -0.0017  0.3322  -0.8509  0.0033
s.e.  0.0675  0.0803  0.0783   0.0676  0.1114   0.0891  0.0005

sigma^2 estimated as 0.001216:  log likelihood=441.4
AIC=-866.81   AICc=-866.15   BIC=-839.37
```

**Output in *Mac***

```
Series: log(via_train) 
ARIMA(4,0,0)(2,1,2)[12] with drift 

Coefficients:
Warning message in sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)):
“NaNs produced”
         ar1     ar2     ar3      ar4     sar1    sar2     sma1     sma2
      0.6157  0.1934  0.0989  -0.0114  -0.3737  0.2908  -0.1539  -0.6143
s.e.     NaN     NaN     NaN   0.0082      NaN     NaN   0.0554   0.0649
       drift
      0.0033
s.e.  0.0005

sigma^2 estimated as 0.001223:  log likelihood=441.66
AIC=-863.32   AICc=-862.31   BIC=-829.03
```

**Added system info**

*Windows*:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods 
[7] base

other attached packages:
 [1] readxl_1.3.1     dplyr_0.8.3      zoo_1.8-7      
 [4] tseries_0.10-47  forecast_8.10    FactoMineR_2.2 
 [7] corrplot_0.84    cluster_2.1.0    factoextra_1.0.6
[10] ggplot2_3.2.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tidyselect_0.2.5     reshape2_1.4.3       purrr_0.3.3        
 [4] urca_1.3-0           lattice_0.20-38      colorspace_1.4-1   
 [7] vctrs_0.2.1          utf8_1.1.4           rlang_0.4.2        
[10] pillar_1.4.3         glue_1.3.1           withr_2.1.2        
[13] TTR_0.23-6           plyr_1.8.5           lifecycle_0.1.0    
[16] stringr_1.4.0        quantmod_0.4-15      timeDate_3043.102  
[19] munsell_0.5.0        gtable_0.3.0         cellranger_1.1.0   
[22] leaps_3.1            labeling_0.3         lmtest_0.9-37      
[25] parallel_3.6.2       curl_4.3             fansi_0.4.0        
[28] xts_0.12-0           Rcpp_1.0.3           scales_1.1.0       
[31] backports_1.1.5      flashClust_1.01-2    scatterplot3d_0.3-41
[34] farver_2.0.1         fracdiff_1.5-1       digest_0.6.23      
[37] stringi_1.4.3        ggrepel_0.8.1        grid_3.6.2          
[40] quadprog_1.5-8       cli_2.0.0            tools_3.6.2        
[43] magrittr_1.5         lazyeval_0.2.2       tibble_2.1.3       
[46] crayon_1.3.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3      zeallot_0.1.0      
[49] MASS_7.3-51.4        assertthat_0.2.1     rstudioapi_0.10    
[52] R6_2.4.1             nnet_7.3-12          nlme_3.1-142       
[55] compiler_3.6.2
```

*Mac* (after update):

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] readxl_1.3.1     dplyr_0.8.3      zoo_1.8-7        tseries_0.10-47 
 [5] forecast_8.10    FactoMineR_2.1   corrplot_0.84    cluster_2.1.0   
 [9] factoextra_1.0.6 ggplot2_3.2.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.8.1        Rcpp_1.0.2           lubridate_1.7.4     
 [4] lattice_0.20-38      class_7.3-15         digest_0.6.22       
 [7] zeallot_0.1.0        utf8_1.1.4           assertthat_0.2.1    
[10] glmnet_3.0-2         ipred_0.9-9          lmtest_0.9-37       
[13] foreach_1.4.7        cellranger_1.1.0     R6_2.4.0            
[16] plyr_1.8.4           backports_1.1.5      stats4_3.6.2        
[19] pillar_1.4.2         rlang_0.4.1          curl_4.2            
[22] lazyeval_0.2.2       caret_6.0-84         rstudioapi_0.10     
[25] data.table_1.12.6    fracdiff_1.5-0       TTR_0.23-6          
[28] rpart_4.1-15         Matrix_1.2-18        labeling_0.3        
[31] splines_3.6.2        gower_0.2.1          stringr_1.4.0       
[34] munsell_0.5.0        compiler_3.6.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[37] urca_1.3-0           shape_1.4.4          nnet_7.3-12         
[40] flashClust_1.01-2    tidyselect_0.2.5     tibble_2.1.3        
[43] prodlim_2019.11.13   quadprog_1.5-8       codetools_0.2-16    
[46] fansi_0.4.0          crayon_1.3.4         withr_2.1.2         
[49] MASS_7.3-51.4        leaps_3.0            recipes_0.1.8       
[52] ModelMetrics_1.2.2   grid_3.6.2           nlme_3.1-142        
[55] gtable_0.3.0         magrittr_1.5         pROC_1.15.3         
[58] scales_1.0.0         quantmod_0.4-15      cli_1.1.0           
[61] stringi_1.4.3        reshape2_1.4.3       scatterplot3d_0.3-41
[64] timeDate_3043.102    vctrs_0.2.0          xts_0.12-0          
[67] generics_0.0.2       lava_1.6.6           iterators_1.0.12    
[70] tools_3.6.2          glue_1.3.1           purrr_0.3.3         
[73] parallel_3.6.2       survival_3.1-8       colorspace_1.4-1
```

**Updated**

New version in *Mac* didn't solve the issue.

**Updated 2**

*Windows*

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.3.1  forecast_8.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        urca_1.3-0        pillar_1.4.3      compiler_3.6.2  
 [5] cellranger_1.1.0  tseries_0.10-47   tools_3.6.2       xts_0.12-0      
 [9] zeallot_0.1.0     lifecycle_0.1.0   tibble_2.1.3      gtable_0.3.0    
[13] nlme_3.1-142      lattice_0.20-38   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.2     
[17] cli_2.0.0         rstudioapi_0.10   curl_4.3          parallel_3.6.2  
[21] dplyr_0.8.3       vctrs_0.2.1       lmtest_0.9-37     grid_3.6.2      
[25] nnet_7.3-12       tidyselect_0.2.5  glue_1.3.1        R6_2.4.1        
[29] fansi_0.4.0       farver_2.0.1      ggplot2_3.2.1     purrr_0.3.3     
[33] TTR_0.23-6        magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.5   scales_1.1.0    
[37] assertthat_0.2.1  quantmod_0.4-15   timeDate_3043.102 colorspace_1.4-1
[41] fracdiff_1.5-1    labeling_0.3      quadprog_1.5-8    utf8_1.1.4      
[45] lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4      zoo_1.8-7
```

*Mac*

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.3.1  forecast_8.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        urca_1.3-0        cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.4.2      compiler_3.6.2   
 [6] tseries_0.10-47   tools_3.6.2       xts_0.12-0        zeallot_0.1.0     tibble_2.1.3     
[11] gtable_0.3.0      nlme_3.1-142      lattice_0.20-38   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.1      
[16] cli_1.1.0         rstudioapi_0.10   curl_4.2          parallel_3.6.2    dplyr_0.8.3      
[21] vctrs_0.2.0       lmtest_0.9-37     grid_3.6.2        nnet_7.3-12       tidyselect_0.2.5 
[26] glue_1.3.1        R6_2.4.0          fansi_0.4.0       ggplot2_3.2.1     purrr_0.3.3      
[31] TTR_0.23-6        magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.5   scales_1.0.0      assertthat_0.2.1 
[36] quantmod_0.4-15   timeDate_3043.102 colorspace_1.4-1  fracdiff_1.5-0    labeling_0.3     
[41] quadprog_1.5-8    utf8_1.1.4        lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4     
[46] zoo_1.8-7
```

Comment: Updated the link. I hope it works now.

Comment: Check your package versions using sessionInfo() on both platforms.

Comment: @RobHyndman, added the system info. I realized my version in Mac is not the last one. Will update `R` to see if solve the problem.

Comment: Can you run them both in a fresh R session so the same packages are loaded in each case. Your session info shows that these R sessions are not identical.

Comment: @RobHyndman, updated the OP. Still nothing change. :(

Comment: You haven't updated the question to show that you are running clean R sessions. The packages loaded are different. So the sessions are not identical.

Comment: I had updated the post, *updated 2*, shows the new information. I guess is what you are asking for. If it's not please give me some advice. Try to run the method with the minimal packages as possible.

Answer (score -4):

After receipt of the data (252 values starting at 1999/1) and analyzing the data as given an appropriate model is (1,1,0)(0,1,0)12 WITHOUT DRIFT with 2 pulse indicators and a deterministic error variance enlargement change (VERY VISUAL) at or around period 108 (2007/12). [image] .

I used AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop to investigate why you might be having problems with this dataset.

The Actual ,Fit and Forecast is here [[image]] with interesting forecasts here [image]

[image]

The model you reported is over-parameterized and under-transformed and probably under-fitting at periods 220 and 89 . This might be the cause of your inconsistent results . [image] Suggests a very strong signal to pinpoint two "unusual" values.

In conclusion the 2 seasonal ar and the 2 seasonal ma coefficients are totally unnecessary and redundant and self-cancelling to each other possibly (probably !) causing severe numerical issues leading to your results.

One of the problems with estimating redundant structure models is that there are an infinite # of solutions which may apply . Think of dividing by 10 and multiplying by 10  OR dividing by 999 and multiplying by 999 ... how to choose which one is correct when neither one is needed.

Comment: AFAIK, `auto.arima` explicitly avoids such models by restricting the characteristic roots of the polynomials not to lie in a "dangerous zone", at least for the nonseasonal part.

Comment: that may be true … what I was trying to point out was that he was not only trying different apps BUT trying different model specification

Comment: No, he is running the _same_ R-code (`auto.arima` from @RobHyndman's forecast package) on both platforms so the issue here is the apparent lack of platform-independence.

Comment: ok ………………………...